# External camera Android OpenCV

Tags: android, opencv, camera, external

Have you ever tried getting live video stream from external camera connected to Android device to later process it with OpenCV functions?

I've found some libraries that seem to allow external camera connection and video grabbing, ex. [UVCCamera](https://github.com/saki4510t/UVCCamera), but OpenCV supports only device's rear and front cameras. Maybe there's some other computer vision library for Android that will do the trick? Or some changes to the device (like rooting or sth)? I'll be glad for any clues!

Comment: Have you got any clues?

Comment: Hi. As far as I know, UVCCamera needs a rooted device and appropirate camera - so it's kind of a monkey business. But if it works, you can write native C++ code and run in with JNI. That's what I believe should happen, but I haven't tried this yet. For a moment, I'm doing my project on a front camera. Maybe I'll return to this topic later.

Comment: i have tried UVCCamera what you mentioned. But no idea to process on object detecting in video (i.e small circles). Guide me if you have any idea about it.